# pandas split to multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I split the second column (SERVICE_SKU) in to multiple columns?

```
           PRODUCT_SKU                                        SERVICE_SKU
                                                                     join
0              01FT562  CON-OSP-C9250I:CON-OS-C9250I:CON-SNTP-C9250I:C...
1              01FT563  CON-SNT-C9132I:CON-S2P-C9132I:CON-OSE-C9132I:C...



print(df3.columns, '\n\n\n')

MultiIndex(levels=[['SERVICE_SKU'], ['join']],
               codes=[[0], [0]])
```

when I use following code to split in to cell i get an error(AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str').

```
df3[
    [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',

    ]
] = df2.SERVICE_SKU.str.split(":", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simpliest is remove second level by [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(1)

df2.SERVICE_SKU.str.split(":", expand=True)
```

If want working with `Multiindex`:

```
df2[('SERVICE_SKU', 'join')].str.split(":", expand=True)
```

Another solution is flatten levels and join:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)

df2.SERVICE_SKU_join.str.split(":", expand=True)
```